# How to make the table format to be compact

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am using a table template code, but I do not really understand the code meaning.
I want to make the table compact, rather than spare out like below.

[image]

I want to be compact like this:

[image]

I do not know where should I change in this table format:

```
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
%  @{\hspace{\tabcolsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}  /% so left some space on the Left and right and delete the last row  @{} /%
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  @{}  % can delete and add "@{\hspace{\tabcolsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}" to left some space on the left and right
}
```

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx,
            threeparttable, tabulary}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf}, 
            justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}



\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
%  @{\hspace{\tabcolsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}  /% so left some space on the Left and right and delete the last row  @{} /%
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  @{}  % can delete and add "@{\hspace{\tabcolsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}" to left some space on the left and right
}
\toprule
{\thead{Stimulus \\ Number}} 
  & {\thead{Class A \\ Sample \\ Number}}
  & {\theadfont N}
  & {\thead{Standard  \\ Deviation \\ (\%)}} \\
\midrule
\textit{Test Case 1}  & 88.57  & 10 & 11.49 \\
\textit{Test Case 2}  & 57.62  & 10 & 13.55 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}



\end{document}
```

Comment: tabular* is intended to expand to a given size (in this case, \textwidth).  Just use a normal tabular and lose all the `\extracolsep`s.  And spend more time reading manuals and less copying templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Simply remove the `fill` command in your table  and replace it with `@{}`

```
@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  @{}
```

becomes

```
@{}
  l
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  @{}
```

Thats it!

### MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using 
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering 
\begin{tabular*}{0.55\textwidth}{
  @{}
  l
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  @{}  
}
\toprule
{\thead{Stimulus \\ Number}} 
  & {\thead{Class A \\ Sample \\ Number}}
  & {\theadfont N}
  & {\thead{Standard  \\ Deviation \\ (\%)}} \\
\midrule
\textit{Test Case 1}  & 88.57  & 10 & 11.49 \\
\textit{Test Case 2}  & 57.62  & 10 & 13.55 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks. How to make the table to be centre? And the line is spread all

Comment: please see edit

Comment: @aan --- -if there is anything else let us know -- you may like to accept the answer and upvote if acceptable

Comment: thanks a lot. Sorry for late reply

Comment: welcome not t o worry

Comment: can we use string instead of digits in the table?

Comment: @alper request a new question linking this answer for a wider audience

Comment: shouldn't be hard to say: replace `S[table-format=2.2]` with `l`